# SQL using CASE with STRING function

Tags: sql, string, case, intersystems-cache

I'm trying to write a SQL query that uses CASE and STRING together and getting an error. 
This is what I'm trying to work on. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
I tried adding in STRING function as well but also does not work.

```
SELECT Case
         when sn.1_code =  1 then 'Attended  -- ' ,  
                                  sn.mult_1 , 
                                  , 'and'  ,  
                                  sn.dict_2 ,  
                                  ' also acted with ' ,  
                                  sn.dict_3 , 
                                  '.' , 
         when sn.1_code =  3 then 'left because ' ,
                                  sn.mult_2 ,
                                  '.' ,
         when sn.dict_1 =  2 then 'Went home' ,
         when sn.dict_1 = 24 then 'Canceled' AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The RDBMS type is Inter systems Cache system. But use SQL to write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other answers have pointed out, you need to concatenate your string values together. From the very very very little I know of Intersystems Cache SQL (I just looked it up), you will [**need to use `||`**](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20141/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_stringmanipulation) to concatenate the values (you can also use the [**CONCAT()**](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_concat) function to do this, but it only allows two paramaters):

```
SELECT Case
     when sn.1_code =  1 then 'Attended  -- ' || 
                              sn.mult_1 || 
                              'and'  ||  
                              sn.dict_2 ||  
                              ' also acted with ' ||  
                              sn.dict_3 || 
                              '.'  
     when sn.1_code =  3 then 'left because ' ||
                              sn.mult_2 ||
                              '.' 
     when sn.dict_1 =  2 then 'Went home' 
     when sn.dict_1 = 24 then 'Canceled' END AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn
```

You also had some extra commas in there, as well as a missing `END` at the end of your [**CASE statement**](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20091/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_case)

Comment: I tried it and also got an error SQL Statement ) expected, , found

Comment: I wonder if it's a version thing, or there is something else I'm missing. Not being familiar with Intersystems Cache, it's hard to tell. Check out Gordon's answer using the `String()` function. Perhaps that will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to concatenate strings.  The actual operator may vary depending on your server software, but the idea would be:

```
SELECT
Case 
  when sn.1_code  = 1 
    then  'Attended  -- ' + sn.mult_1 + 'and' + sn.dict_2 + ' also acted with ' + sn.dict_3 + '.' 
  when sn.1_code  = 3 
    then 'left because ' + sn.mult_2 + '.' , 
  when  sn.dict_1 = 2 
    then 'Went home'  ,
  when sn.dict_1 = 24 
    then 'Canceled'   
End AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn
```

Answer (score 2):

Intersystems Cache appears to support the two argument `concat()` function (ala Oracle).  It also supports `string()`.  This should do what you want:

```
SELECT (Case when sn.1_code =  1
            then string('Attended  -- ', sn.mult_1, 'and',  sn.dict_2 ,  ' also acted with ', sn.dict_3 ,  '.' ) 
            when sn.1_code =  3
            then string('left because ', sn.mult_2 , '.' )
            when sn.dict_1 =  2
            then 'Went home'
            when sn.dict_1 = 24
            then 'Canceled'
        end) AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn;
```

The `case` statement also needs an `end`.

Comment: I tried it and got an error SQL statement IDENTIFIER expected, ? found

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to concatenate, as it seems to me, you do it with the + character, and not the comma:

```
SELECT
Case when sn.1_code  = 1 then  'Attended  -- ' +  
sn.mult_1 +
'and' +
sn.dict_2 +  
' also acted with ' +
sn.dict_3 +
'.' 
when sn.1_code  = 3 
then 'left because ' + sn.mult_2 + '.'  
when  sn.dict_1 = 2 then 'Went home'  
when sn.dict_1 = 24 then 'Canceled' 
END  AS 'Attendance'
FROM db.sn
```

Without seeing your example with the String function, I don't know what you were trying to do with it.

Comment: Tried it and did not workgot an error saying " Error in ROW SQL Statement: Identifier expected, ? found

Comment: Ok, my answer was assuming SQL Server, but I have no knowledge of the RDBMS you are using.  Try JNevill's answer.